# How to avoid quotes from a comma separated string joined from a list in python

Tags: python, string, csv, quotes

I have created a comma separated string by joining strings from a list in Python 3.5 and use it to write it to an INI file using configobj. Here is a sample Python script used in a Ubuntu 16.04 terminal:

```
sudo python3 << EOP
from configobj import ConfigObj

config=ConfigObj("myconfig.ini")
config['items']={}
itemlist=('item1','item2')
csvstr=",".join(list)
config['items']['itemlist'] = csvstr
config.write()
EOP
```

This writes the string with quotes as "item1,item2" as shown below.

```
[items]
itemlist = "item1,item2"
```

However, if the items are joined with other characters such as ";", it writes the string without quotes! How to make it write the comma separated string without quotes?

Appreciate for any tips or solution.

Comment: Overriding builtin names such as `list` and `str` is a terrible practice.

Comment: Thanks Ilja for the comments. I have edited and corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commas are reserved for field separation and so you cannot have (unless you [really want to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39636774/2681632)) an unquoted string value with commas in it. Apparently you do want to have a list of values, so just pass a list as the value:

```
from configobj import ConfigObj

config=ConfigObj("myconfig.ini")
config['items']={}
itemlist=['item1','item2']
config['items']['itemlist'] = itemlist
config.write()
```

This will result in

```
[items]
itemlist = item1, item2
```

Comment: Thanks Ilja and Tiger-222, both the solutions work. I would use the list as value as it is straight forward.

Comment: By the way, using list directly adds a space after comma, which is not acceptable in one of my config files. Is there a way to prevent adding space?

Comment: Ah, well in that case you should adhere to [@tiger-222's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39636774/2681632). Documentation on [`list_values`](https://configobj.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configobj.html#list-values) especially mentions having to do own parsing/custom formats as a use case.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use the `list_values` keyword:

```
config = ConfigObj('myconfig.ini', list_values=False)
```

[As the documentation says](https://configobj.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configobj.html#configobj-specifications), if `list_values=False` then single line values are not quoted or unquoted when reading and writing.

The result:

```
[items]
itemlist = item1,item2
```